# How to display the current time in right side corner of Text Area and mesage Text in left corner?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsp

In my Customer side chat application jsp page , I have a text area that displays the messages from the Agent side and also displays the message from the customer .

That works fine.My javaScript code is,

```
function sendMessage(){
    message =trim( document.getElementById("message").value);
    document.getElementById("message").value = "";

    if(message != null && message !="null"  && message !=""){

        try
        {
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
            {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                {
                    var checkMsg = trim(xmlhttp.responseText.toString());
                    textarea = document.getElementById('textarea'); 

                    if(checkMsg != "null" && checkMsg != null && trim(checkMsg).length != 0) {
                        if(trim(textarea.value) == ""){
                            textarea.value = message = checkMsg;
                            textarea.scrollTop = textarea.scrollHeight;
                        }
                        else{
                            textarea.value += "\n"+checkMsg;
                            textarea.scrollTop = textarea.scrollHeight;
                        }

                    }
                }
            };

            xmlhttp.open("POST", "SendMessageAction",true);
            xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("charset","UTF-8");
            xmlhttp.send("sessionId="+encodeURIComponent(sessionId)+"&userId="+encodeURIComponent(userId)+"&securekey="+encodeURIComponent(secureKey)+"&message="+encodeURIComponent(message)+"&sid="+Math.random());

        }
        catch(err)
        {
            alert(err.description);
        }
    }

}
```

In that I need to include the current time with the every messages appending in the text area at the right side corner of text area.

I can append the current time with messages but I need to append it in right side corner of textarea with every messages?

How can I do this.Please give some ideas or some code.

Comment: As far as I know a textarea can only contain regular text. So that means you can not apply any formatting on specific parts of the textarea. The closest you can probably get is by padding the timestamp with some spaces, but that's error prone at best. If that's not good enough, you'll have to split the textbox into multiple parts, pretty likely one part for every timestamp.

Comment: Are you trying to show the current time to the user/agent on the textbox or are you trying to append the current time to message text when it is sent?

Comment: Thanks for supporting me.How can I split the textarea in to two parts ? that is one for messages and for to display the current time. ?

Comment: @miracc I am trying to display the time , When the message was sent . It should be need to displayed in the customer side with the messages.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that displays current date/time:

If you want, you can extract just the time lines for time only.

```
function update(){
time = new Date();
year = (time.getFullYear());
month = (time.getMonth() + 1);
date = time.getDate();
hours = time.getHours();
mins = time.getMinutes();
secs = time.getSeconds();
if(mins.length<2){mins = "0"+secs}
if(secs.length<2){secs = "0"+secs}
if(month.length<2){month = "0"+secs}
if(date.length<2){date  = "0"+secs}


// Config Starts
if(hours>12){hours=hours-12}else{hours}
format = year+"-"+month+"-"+date+"  @  "+hours+":"+mins+":"+secs;
document.form1.box1.value = format;
// Config Ends
}
setInterval("update()",1000);
```

To display the results use:

```
<script>
#right
    {
        float: right;
    }
</script>

<div id="right">
<p>Current Date/Time is: <INPUT name="box1" type="text" size="20"></p>
</div>
```